# Network interfaces in deban: wifi and usb-ethernet

Tags: debian, wifi, network-interface

Just installed Debian on an iMac5,1.

X11 simply doesn't work so this is all on the command line.

I have the built-in ethernet connected to my home broadband hub. All good.

I'd like to get the wifi working.

```
# lspci
...
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 01)
...
# apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
# apt-get install iw
# apt-get install wireless-tools
```

```
# apt-get install connman
# connmanctl
connmanctl> enable wifi
Error wifi: Method "SetProperty" with signature "sv" on interface "net.connman.Technology" doesn't exist

connmanctl>
```

Now what?!
How can I tell if the driver is indeed installed and working?

Second: I have a USB ethernet adapter -- eventually I'll want to bridge the networks.

```
# lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b95:772a ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772A Fast Ethernet
...
```

Again: now what?

And this third interface: is it wifi or USB?

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:cb:9c:eb:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.51/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.14/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::216:cbff:fe9c:ebce/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enx00808e8c92f8: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:80:8e:8c:92:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

(I want the machine to have the static address 192.168.1.51 and have set `/etc/network/interfaces` accordingly, but it seems to be ignoring this and getting another address from the router.)

**Update: wlan0 appeared and interfaces is ignored**

```
root@imac51:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#allow-hotplug enp2s0
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.51
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
root@imac51:~#
root@imac51:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:cb:9c:eb:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.14/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::216:cbff:fe9c:ebce/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enx00808e8c92f8: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:80:8e:8c:92:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:17:f2:99:7b:9b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
root@imac51:~#
```

Rebooting seems have made `wlan0` appear and `connmann` is doing something. A case of *turn it off and on again*...

Fiddled about with `connmanctrl` and now it seems to have connected -- after another restart. Is it possible to change the name of the computer as it appears on the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `connman` does something with DHCP. It's not necessary anyway so best not to use it. Use `iw` (command for doing things with wifi) and `wpasupplicant` (adds `wpa-` commands to `/etc/network/interfaces`) and this in the `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid RWB
        wpa-psk password
```

Note that for this machine the WiFi hardware is Broadcom 4321 and the correct package is `firmware-bc43-installer`; the installer guesses a different package that is wrong and has the consequence that it will join an AP but have no network access. This affects the Ubuntu 20 and Mint 10 installers.